# Django -- Common Scenario: Product with M2M -> Categories. How do I efficiently query all categories on a product queryset?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to cut down on my query counts and have a question.

I have a typical product model set up that can have multiple categories.

`Product M2M -> Category`

I have a function defined that pulls the main category (lets just say its the latest one):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def main_category(self):
        return self.category.latest('id')
        # or any other way to determine main category
```

I iterate through products in my template, displaying its main category.

```
{% for product in products %}
    Name: {{ product.name }}
    Category: {{ product.main_category }}
{% endfor %}
```

This causes a query for every product. How can I get it all in less queries, in Python?

For my other `MultipleObjectFK -> Product` models I've been able to [partition my queries (slideshow)](http://www.slideshare.net/zeeg/db-tips-tricks-django-meetup) and use just 2 queries + python, 
 but I can't seem to apply it to M2M because when I pull the Categories that are referenced in my product queryset, I have no idea which product triggered the category match.

I'm leaning towards setting up a `main_category` field on my model that has a category ID calculated whenever there's an M2MField changed signal.

Thanks for your time : )

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do. Create a `through` model for the ManyToMany relationship, and stick a boolean field on that model to indicate the `main_category` status. Then, you can just query that model, using `select_related()` so it automatically follows the two foreign keys - and now you can iterate through the through objects and get both Product and Category without any extra queries.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through="ProductCategory")

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View:

```
prod_cats = ProductCategory.objects.filter(main=True).select_related()
```

template:

```
{% for prod_cat in prod_cats %}
    Name: {{ prod_cat.product.name }}
    Category: {{ prod_cat.category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Really interesting use of the "through" model, I'll remember this for next time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this idea!  It *feels* odd, but works. All products should have a category, so I could rewrite everything using ProductCategory instead of Product. Or at least reduce to 2 queries w/o any changes elsewhere by doing ProductCategory.filter(main=True,pk__in=productqueryset_ids).select_related()and adding a main_category attribute to the original product queryset.